# How to echo to running process in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, process

If I have a C++ program that expects input to cin from the console during run-time, how can I automate this input from a shell script? I also need to store its output in a file but that part is easy. I have researched different ways including echo-ing it to the file descriptor of the pid in /proc, but nothing seems to work.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/sh
g++ -o runme source.cpp
echo <<EOT | ./runme > output
expected program input
more expected program input
even more
EOT
```

Note that each line of input requires an "enter key-press" to be read by cin in the program, which I am assuming should happen since the program input in the script is separated by new-lines. Here, the program gets executed but the same output is produced in the file regardless of what I put before the EOT so it's not being entered to cin of the program as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The form of I/O redirection you want is called a [here document](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and does not involve `echo` at all:

```
./runme <<EOF
expected program input
more expected program input
even more
EOF
```

With output redirection:

```
./runme <<EOF > output
expected program input
more expected program input
even more
EOF
```

If you insist on using `echo`, in principle you could do:

```
echo -e "expected program input\nmoreexpected program input\neven more\n" | ./runme
```

where the `-e` option enables the interpretation of backslash escapes, such  as the newlines indicated by `\n` in the argument of `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI, `echo` does not read from its standard input (which a here document provides); you would want to use `cat` instead:

```
cat <<EOF | ./runme > output
...
...
...
EOF
```

But this is a useless use of `cat`, since you can just connect the here document to `runme`'s standard input directly as shown by [Thomas Nyman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19136655/1126841).